# Embedded ressource in VB.NET vs. C#

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, embedded-resource

Question:

I have embedded ressources (SQL scripts) in my application, which get used by my DAL dll, which i use in my application.

Now the embedded ressources reside in folder SQL/SQL_Server/ and SQL/MS_Access/.

I read them out at runtime, using the server type (Access, SqlServer) and the filename.

This works fine, because the embedded ressourcename is:
myappname.Folder.Subfolder.FileName, e.g. appname.SQL.MS_Access.Filename

However, if I now call this dll from VB, the ressourcename only is:
myappname.FileName

Is there a way to get the folder name of the embedded ressource in VB.NET ? 
Or to include it when compiling ? 
Or to distinguish in the DAL between a VB.NET host and a C# host ?

```
System.Reflection.Assembly asmDataSourceAssembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly();

string strRessourceRoot = null;
foreach (string strThisRessourceName in asmDataSourceAssembly.GetManifestResourceNames())
```

Then compare with strThisRessourceName.ToLower().EndsWith("sql.foldername.filename")

To be more exact:
Main.exe in C# with embedded ressources + DAL.DLL in C# = **works**
Main.exe in VB.NET with embedded ressources + DAL.DLL in C# = **not working** because GetManifestResourceNames() only gets the filename of the embedded ressources, and not the folder names as well. As an additional side effect, one cannot embed several files with the same name in a VB.NET exe, even when they are in a different folder (compile time error).
(the same thing works absolutely fine in C#).

Comment: What code are you using to load the resource?

Comment: That's your C# code; what about the VB code that you say isn't working? It does seem strange that you're using `GetEntryAssembly()` if your SQL scripts are compiled into your DAL assembly as well?

Comment: There's no VB code. It's the C# code in the DAL dll that get's the embedded ressources from the main .exe, which is a VB.NET executable. The VB code is only calling methods in the DAL, and the DAL then accesses the SQL scripts in the embedded ressources of the main .exe.

Comment: To be clear, have you got: main.exe (written is c#, with the resources in it) calling a vb.net assembly which calls your DAL assembly (again, written in c#); and this behaving differently to: same exe calling through different middle assembly (this time in c#) calling through to same DAL assembly?

Comment: @Rowland Shaw: Absolutely wrong. I have a main.exe (written in VB.NET, with resources in it), which references DAL.dll (written in C#, that does all the database work), and DAL.DLL extracts the SQL scripts [=ressources] which are embedded in main.exe. Then main.exe calls functions in DAL.dll (e.g. execute insert_table_xy.sql).

Answer (score 2):

The VB compiler does not implicitly map subfolders to be sub-namespaces, therefore, to achieve the effect of sub namespacing below the default namespace for the assembly (as configured through project properties, defaults to the project name), you will need to include the sub namespaces in the file name

Comment: This is what I have done in the interim, but it is very annoying and undesirable.

Comment: What I am searching is a way to explicitly map subfolders to sub-namespaces, or just specify the subnamespace manually.

Answer (score 1):

There is actually a difference on how C# and VB.NET handles this, but It is the language of the DLL that the embedded resource exists in that decides the namespace. We've had problems with the paths changing after we've converted some old VB.NET code into C# with automated tools.

More here: http://weblogs.asp.net/istofix/archive/2008/10/21/embedded-resources-in-vb-net-and-c-projects.aspx

Comment: What you write is correct. But I already realized this, and since this is the problem, and not the solution, I don't quite understand the point of your post.